# How can I put this php into a image background url?

Tags: php, image, background

I would be very very grateful for help with this:
I have a bootstrap carousel that I want to include pictures from a database. I want it to appear as background image like this:

```
<div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('link to image')">
```

This is the PHP-snippet that I want to put in place for the above 'link to image':

```
<?php
$img_url = "images/programpics/"; {
  echo '<img src="' . $img_url . $row_firstrow[ 'show_tix_phone' ] . '"id="pic1" alt="Something here" />';
}
?>
```

Comment: why do you have opening and closing brackets ?

Comment: style="background-image: url('link to image') - it's generate javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Link to image' is a part of style, not allow html tags like 'img' and angle brackets. Example syntax:

```
background-image: url('images/bg.jpg')
```

With this in mind you code must be like this:

```
<div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url('<?php
$img_url = "images/programpics/"; 
{
  echo $img_url . $row_firstrow[ 'show_tix_phone' ];
}
?>')" id="pic1" alt="Something here" />';
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope help:

```
<div class="carousel-item" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $img_url . $row_firstrow[ 'show_tix_phone' ] ?>)">
```